# Why my output is 3 i need an explaination

Tags: python, python-3.x

There's my code

```
num = 0 
for i in range(5, 0 ,-1):
    num += i > num 

print(num)
```

and this is the output i got

```
3
```

Who's know it please, explain it clearly

Comment: May I recommend http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html ?

Answer (score 5):

adding a print statement in the loop:

```
num = 0
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(num, i, i > num, int(i > num))
    num += i > num

print(num)
```

gives:

```
# num, i, i > num, int(i > num)
  0    5  True     1
  1    4  True     1
  2    3  True     1
  3    2  False    0
  3    1  False    0
```

`i > num` is a boolean... `True` is just (a thin wrapper over) `1`; `False` is `0`.

Comment: Just for simple example `sum([True,True,False])` is `2`.